# Как создать массив с буквами кириллицы в Java?

Tags: java

При создании массива с русскими символами компилятор выдаёт такую ошибку(см. изображение).

Вот код. Его задача проверять введенное пользователем сообщение на латинице(lowermail) и в случае наличия в нём символов русского алфавита изменять значение isSpam на true.

```
char[] cyrLetters = {"й", "ц", "у", "к", "е", "н", "г", "ш", "щ", "з", "х", "ф", "ы", "в", "а", "п", "р", "о", "л", "д", "ж", "э", "я", "ч", "с", "м", "и", "т", "ь", "б", "ю", "ъ", "ё"};

    boolean isSpam = false; 

for(String x: cyrLetters){
        if(lowermail.contains(x)){
            isSpam = true;
        }
    }
```

[image: Ошибка компилятора]

Comment: По поводу ошибки не знаю, а по поводу алгоритма, я бы добавил команду break, в случае нахождения элемента, для выхода из цикла, зачем проверять другие символы, если уже содержит русские символы)

Comment: Т.е. должно получиться так:  if(lowermail.contains(x)){ isSpam = true; break; }

Comment: Да, примерно так.

Comment: @margareq, если хочется использовать `cyrLetters`, то сделайте инициализацию в алфавитном порядке. Проверить все ли буквы и нет ли повторов сейчас займет необосновано много времени.

Comment: судя по ошибке, компилятор пытается считать файл программы в кодировке cp1252, а там внутри utf8 или что-то подобное. Попробуйте запускать с параметром `-Dfile.encoding=utf-8`

Comment: судя по всему кодировка вашего java фала не utf8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы объявили массив символов (`char`), а инициализируете его строками (`String`). Либо поменяйте `char[]` на `String[]`, либо двойные кавычки на одинарные.

Answer (score 1):

Если необходимо проверить вхождение русских символов в строку, то можно воспользоваться методом `String.matches` и регулярным выражением:

```
boolean isSpam = lowerMail.matches(".*[А-яЁё].*");
```

В регулярном выражение `.` - представляет собой сокращенную форму записи для символьного класса, совпадающего с любым символом; `*` - любое количество экземпляров элемента (в том числе и нулевое); `[А-яЁё]` - любая буква русского алфавита.

Comment: Тогда лучше уж так: `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[А-яЁё]");
        boolean isSpam = p.matcher(lowerMail).find();`

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключалась в компиляторе, так как это был онлайн-компилятор без поддержки кириллицы, он и выводил подобные "крякозябры" в консоль.